# notepad++ - trying to reformat some stuff

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a CSV that basically has rows that look like:

```
06444|WidgetAdapter 6444|Description:

Here is a description.
Maybe some more.
|0
```

The text in the third field is always different and varying, and I'm trying to replace all newlines within it only with `<br>`, so it ends up as

```
06444|WidgetAdapter 6444|Description: <br>Here is a description.<br>Maybe some more.<br>|0
```

edit:

I basically need to get rid of all linebreaks so each line is a proper VALUE|VALUE|VALUE|VALUE. Normalize/beautify/clean it.

None of my tools can import this properly, phpMyAdmin chokes, etc.
There are linebreaks within the field, there are doublequotes that are not escaped, etc.

Example other field:

```
08681|Book 08681|"Testimonial" - Person

You should buy this.|
```

Example of another field:

```
39338|Itemizer||
```

Comment: Deleting my answer, it looks more complicated than a simple find/replace can handle...

Comment: looks like you're going to have to clarify your question please :)

Comment: I concur with BoltClock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you have 4 columns, you can easily parse your data. For example, here's a PHP line that results in an array with all data. Each line in the array is another array with all capturing groups: `[0]` has the whole match, and `[1]`-`[4]` with each column:

```
$pattern = '/^([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)$/m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The pattern is extremely simple: it takes 4 values (not pipe signs), separated by 3 pipes. Once you have the data, you can easily rebuild it the way you want, for example by using  [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).
Note that you cannot reliably parse the data if the first and last columns can also containg new lines.

Working example: http://ideone.com/gG0K3

Comment: I don't always know if I have 4 columns.

Comment: Last columns have a mix of \r or \n for newlines, or both, either in text or the actual character. Not every line has the same amount of columns. Unfortunately. Trying to mess around with this atm.

Comment: @Jmoon - Hmm... but only the 3rd might have new lines? If so, `/^[^|\r\n]*\|[^|\r\n]*\|[^|]*\|([^\r\n]*)$/m` might work for you, and you'd have to split on `|`. I'm not sure how solvable it is... I'd be happy to hear more details `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If needed, it is possible to target these newlines using a regular expression. The idea is to find only newlines that are followed by one extra value, and then only whole lines. We can check the number of values after the current newline is 1 modulo 4, so we know we're at the 3rd column:

```
(?:\r\n?|\n)(?=[^|]*\|[^\n\r|]*\s*(?:^(?:[^|]*\|){3}[^\n\r|]*$\s*)*\Z)
```

Or, with (some) explanations:

```
(?:\r\n?|\n)   # Match a newline
(?=            # that is before...
    [^|]*\|[^\n\r|]*\s*               # one more separator and value
    (?:^(?:[^|]*\|){3}[^\n\r|]*$\s*)* # and some lines with 4 values.
    \Z                                # until the end of the string.
)
```

I couldn't get it to work on Notepad++ (it didn't even match `[\r\n]`), but it seems to work well on other engines:

- Rubular (Ruby): http://rubular.com/r/NsbTNg9vCT
- RegExr (Action Script): http://regexr.com?2u1iu
- Regex Hero (.Net): http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=215ac2bb-811b-48dd-8c00-6dcfadfae2f2

Comment: Important notice: this approach might be a little too slow for 300,000 rows.